# IntellijIDEA trae opciones en chino

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

esta es mi primera pregunta.
El problema es el siguiente, instale el IDE intellije y este me funciona bien, pero trae algunas opciones en letras chinas como se ve en la imagen.
Ya probe cuanta cosa vi en internet, alguien que por favor me ayude a solucionar o me indique que debo de hacer.
Desde ya muchas gracias por sus ayudas y comentarios.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esas opciones en particular dependen de archivos en tu proyecto.

Comment: no es chino, es koreano. Segurmente el nombre del proyecto lo pusieron en coreano en tu pom.xml. Deberías agregarlo a la pregunta

Comment: Si puedes indica de donde copiaste el repositorio, seguramente el repositorio que copiaste esta en ese idioma.

Comment: El proyecto lo cree desde cero, todo lo inicie desde cero, solo que desde que instale el IDE me salen esas opciones en ese idioma

Comment: Lo qu ehe visto es que  es solo cuando creo proyectos con Spring-boot, uso Java nativo y funciona bien.